# how to take a backup of a table which is created from a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I have a stored procedure `hello` which generates a table. I want to take the backup of that table every week using sql job. Can someone tell me a command for that.
So far I have tried to take a backup of an existing table `employee` in database `emp` using the command:

```
DECLARE @table VARCHAR(128),
@file VARCHAR(255),
@cmd VARCHAR(512)
SET @table = 'dbo.employee' --  Table Name which you want to backup
SET @file = 'C:\Users\vibhav.sarraf\Documents\New_folder\' + @table + '_' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)
+ '.dat'
SET @cmd = 'bcp ' + @table + ' out ' + @file + ' -n -T '
EXEC emp..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

which generates a 0 Byte file with and gives an error:

Error

> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'dbo.employee'.

which I think is because I am not using `use emp;`

Note:- I dont want to create any table in my database

Answer (score 1):

The `bcp` program runs outside the current script, hence doesn't knows anything about the "current database". You need to explicitly tell it where that table is located by setting the database in the command line (otherwise it ends up looking for it in `master`.

So, change it to this:

```
SET @cmd = 'bcp ' + @table + ' out ' + @file + ' -n -T -d' + @database
```

where `@database` is the name of the DB containing the table in question.

Look at the [bcp documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802) for details.

Comment: "otherwise it ends up looking for it in master". My understanding is that it would connect to the default database of the user provided in the bcp command if -d is not provided.

Comment: Great that worked. But my actual problem is to create a backup of a table generated by a procedure

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(128),
@file VARCHAR(255),
@cmd VARCHAR(512),
@database varchar(128)
SET @database = 'jiradb'
SET @query = '"hello"' --where hello is the stored procedure
SET @file = 'C:\Users\vibhav.sarraf\Documents\New_folder\query.txt'
SET @cmd = 'bcp ' + @query + ' queryout ' + @file + ' -c -T -d ' + @database
EXEC jiradb..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```